# How to change the reference level for Risk Ratio in logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, reference, regression, logistic-regression

```
  Survey.ID          Quit        Boss            Subord Subord2 Subord3       Subord4
1         1             0         0               0     0            1          0
2         2             1         0               0     1            0          0
3         3             0         0               0     0            0          0
4         4             0         0               0     0            1          0
5         5             0         0               0     0            1          0
6         6             1         0               0     0            1          0
```

I have a df above. Each of the variables is a binary variable that categorizes if someone is a boss, or a certain level of subordinate. I am trying to see what is most predictive of someone quitting the past month. I am using the logistic regression

```
model  <- glm(Quit ~ Subord, family=binomial, data = df)
summary(model)
exp(cbind(RR = coef(model), confint.default(model)))
```

I would like to find the Relative Risk (RR) for each group of employees: Boss, Subord, Subord2, Subord3, Subord4. However, I would like to reference group to be Subord4. I believe right now, the reference is set to boss? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Sample data

```
df <-
 structure(list(id = 1:6, Quit = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Boss = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Subord = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Subord2 = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Subord3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Subord4 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  #Create a single column of variables: Boss Subord Subord2 Subord3 Subord4
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id,Quit)) %>% 
  #Keeping only those with value = 1
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  #Making "Subord4" the baseline, as the first level of the factor
  mutate(name = fct_relevel(as.factor(name),"Subord4")) %>% 
  glm(data = .,formula = Quit~name, family=binomial)
```